# Remove git stashes beyond N

Tags: git, git-stash

I stash changes in git regularly and have built up quite a long stash list (and 'stache, coincidentally). My current repo has 68 stashes. Is there a way to cleanup the stash list by clearing all but the N most recent stashes?

Options I've looked into:

`git stash clear` - removes the entire stash list

`git stash drop <stash>`- removes the specific `<stash>`

The first option would remove the entire stash list, the latter would require a few dozen commands. I'm looking for something along the lines of how `git rebase -i HEAD~N` works, where a number can be supplied to the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a little shell loop. Note that when you drop the *N*'th stash all the subsequent ones get renumbered; and `git stash drop stash@{N}` fails (noisily, and does nothing) when there is no *N*'th stash. Thus you can just use:

```
while git stash drop stash@{30}; do done
```

which does nothing at all inside the loop, relying on the failure to exit the loop.  (Replace 30 with desired value for *N*, obviously.)

Edit: `bash` requires at least one command inside the loop:

```
while git stash drop stash@{30}; do :; done
```

This uses the built-in do-nothing `:` command, so it looks a bit weird.  If you prefer, the built-in `true` command also works:

```
while git stash drop stash@{30}; do true; done
```

(The built-in `false` command also works, but returns a failing exit code, and hence is not suitable in scripts that may have `-e` set.)

Comment: This is awesome. Trying to add it as an alias so I can run ``git rs 100`` where rs is the alias and 100 is the Nth stash. So in my alias file I have:
``alias rs = "!f() { while git stash drop stash@{$1}; do done }; f"``. This doesn't work. I get an error ``syntax error near unexpected token `done'``

Comment: @Jeff: some shells (bash in particular) require a command inside the loop. The no-op `:` command suffices: `while ...; do :; done`

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple `npm` package for trimming a `git` stash to a specified number. Once installed a simple `git-trim-stash 10` will trim the `git` stash to the 10 most recent stashes.

The package is extremely lightweight and has zero dependencies.

More info on the [npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-trim-stash).